# Can a person who has Marfan Syndrome grow muscle?

Tags: exercise, strength, bodybuilding, muscle-mass

Marfan syndrome is a weakness on the connective tissues, this means that numerous if not all tissues of the body are weak and is very easily to get injured, but I wonder, does Marfan syndrome prevents the grow of muscle?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly does not completely prevent it. One of my roommates had Marfan's and, while lean, he had enough strength to be able to hurl a 200-lb male across the room (he also had a bit of a temper on him). He did not have a workout regimen, but had grown up on a farm, so he probably grew up with a fair amount of physical activity.

I suspect that someone with Marfans would have to be careful about over-stressing their tendons, but could still develop muscle.